# Event Sceduling with MySql Databases to Remove Past Events

Tags: mysql, database, events, scheduler

I have a PHP application that allows admin users to add new events, edit them and delete them for customers to book.

What I want to do is automatically delete events after they have happened.

Each event record in the events table (ID, Start_Date, Course_ID, Place) has a start date so I basically want the database to ask every day 'Are there any records in the events table where Today's Date > Start_Date'. If there are, they must be deleted.

I have been reading this web page http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ for information on how to create scheduled events on MySql databases.

However, I am struggling with where to type in these MySql commands. I am using a program called **Sequel Pro** (For Mac) and the only place I can see to type in these commands is in the query box.

However, when I type in

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

I receive an error:

```
Unknown system variable 'event_scheduler'
```

Can anyone help me?

I am aware there are a lot of event scheduling based questions, but none of them seem to help.

Comment: Perhaps missing from your version of MySQL.

Comment: It claims to work with A MySQL 3, 4 or 5 Server.

Comment: Perhaps your host has disabled it.

Comment: Perhaps that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that you have an answer to accept in case I'm right...

Perhaps your host has disabled event scheduling in MySQL.

Comment: Ye, I'll give it a few days in case anyone has a better idea but it looks like you're right